# Import Error in flask application

Tags: python, flask

I have an application. Below is o/p of tree command -

```
app
|-- main
|   |-- lib
|   |   |-- constants.py
|   |   |-- helper.py
|   |   `-- __init__.py
|   `-- src
|       |-- __init__.py
|       `-- web.py
```

**web.py**

```
from flask import Flask, request  
app = Flask(__name__)

from lib.helper import endpoints
.....
Some code
.....
if __name__ == '__main__':
     app.run('0.0.0.0', 5433, debug=True)
```

I am getting this error

> ImportError: No module named lib.helper.

where am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's your PYTHONPATH?

Comment: Do you get same error when running app from src folder and from main folder ?

Comment: @ThePavolC yes getting same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from flask import Flask, request  
app = Flask(__name__)

import sys
from os.path import abspath, dirname
sys.path.insert(0, dirname(dirname(abspath(__file__))))

from lib.helper import endpoints
.....
Some code
.....
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run('0.0.0.0', 5433, debug=True)
```

Comment: it worked for me. Can u pls explain, why the abspath and dirname is required?

Comment: @frehat the line - sys.path.insert(0, dirname(dirname(abspath(__file__))))  introduce the search path in pythonpath ?

Comment: Yes. `__file__` path to executing script, `abspath` to make it absolute in case of symbolic links and two `dirname`s to go up. Then, we include that directory.

Answer (score 0):

Lib module is outside of src folder, need to go up one folder up and use that model.

```
from ..lib.helper
```

Answer (score 0):

Or else a fully qualified namespace as

```
from app.main.lib
```